# Помогите составить SQL-запрос с условным UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Есть входные данные

```
$inv1player // с id предмета в инвентаре
$dropenemy // с id предмета вываливающегося из врага
invsum1  // количество вещей в инвентаре в базе mysql
```

Нужно сделать mysql запрос UPDATE(обновление записи) в котором должна работать логика, если id предмета в инвентаре равен id предмета вываливающегося из врага, то invsum1 + 1

Мои извращения:

```
$drop_update = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET IF('".$inv1player."'='".$dropenemy."',invsum1 = invsum1 + 1) WHERE login = '".$LOGIN."'");
```

Comment: `update users set invsum1 = invsum1 + 1 where login = '$LOGIN' and $inv1player=$dropenemy`

Comment: *в котором должна работать логика* Вообще-то дерьмо логика - любой чих, и в таблицах хрень. Нужно тупо при изменении в инвентаре пересчитывать (скажем, триггером) количество предметов в нём.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, работает!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if($inv1player == $dropenemy)
{
 $invsum1 += 1;
}
$drop_update = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE users SET invsum1 = '".$invsum1."' WHERE login = '".$LOGIN."'");
```

Comment: Лучше не пытаться склеивать SQL-запрос из составных частей. Надо воспользоваться более продвинутой техникой - подготовленными запросами. К тому же, так будет меньше вероятности добавить уязвимость.

Comment: Так тоже работает) Спасибо

Comment: @Антон Интересно, зачем вообще делать update в БД в случае если увеличивать поле не надо ? Если вы указали полностью весь запрос и он других полей не меняет, то надо сам это запрос положить внутрь if. Кроме того опасно делать update на переменную, потому что значение в БД уже могло измениться (если запись заранее не была заблокирована). Внутрь if я бы положил явно `update ... set invsum1=invsum1+1 ...`. И если условие if не сработало то и в update делать нечего

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за комментарий.